# ¿Como crear dos intervalos de tiempo diferentes dentro de la misma función?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Bueno como verán la siguiente constante sirve para realizar el efecto de máquina de escribir... mi problema es que no se como aplicar dos intervalos de tiempo diferentes a las dos condiciones: el primer if sería el que "borra" el texto y el else estaría haciendo que el texto se "escriba" y lo que yo quisiera es que el borrado sea mas rápido que la escritura =>

```
<body>
<div id="prin"><p id="texto" class="efecto">asdasdasd</p></div>
<script src="probadormaquina.js"></script>
```

```
 let etiqueta = document.getElementById("texto");


const escritura = (texto = "",tiempo = 1000, etiquet = "") => {
    let contador = 0;
    etiquet.innerHTML = "";
    let j = texto.length;
    let caracteres = texto.split("");
    let escribir = setInterval( () => {      
    if (contador == texto.length) {
        
        etiqueta.style.borderRightColor = "black";
        etiquet.innerHTML = texto.substring(0,j);
        j--;
        if (j < 0) {
            j = texto.length;
            contador = 0;
        }
    }
    else {
        etiquet.innerHTML += caracteres[contador];
        contador++;
        let variable = (texto.length - 4);
        if (contador >= variable & contador <= texto.length & contador%2 == 0) {
            console.log("ahora aparezco");
            etiqueta.style.borderRightColor = "white"; 
        }
        else {
            etiqueta.style.borderRightColor = "black";
        }
 
}
} , tiempo)
}
escritura("hola mundo    ", 500, etiqueta);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes usar un tiempos distinto para ambas acciones, no puedes usar un `setInterval` porque siempre se ejecuta en el mismo tiempo. Puedes por el contrario usar `setTimeout` para que según la acción, se ejecute en tiempos distintos.

```js
const escritura = (texto = "", tiempoEscritura = 1000, tiempoBorrado = 500, etiquet = "") => {
  let contador = 0;
  etiquet.innerHTML = "";
  let j = texto.length;
  let caracteres = texto.split("");
  const escribir = function() {
    if (contador == texto.length) {

      etiquet.style.borderRightColor = "black";
      etiquet.innerHTML = texto.substring(0, j);
      j--;
      if (j < 0) {
        j = texto.length;
        contador = 0;
      }
      setTimeout(escribir, tiempoBorrado);
    } else {
      etiquet.innerHTML += caracteres[contador];
      contador++;
      let variable = (texto.length - 4);
      if (contador >= variable & contador <= texto.length & contador % 2 == 0) {
        console.log("ahora aparezco");
        etiquet.style.borderRightColor = "white";
      } else {
        etiquet.style.borderRightColor = "black";
      }
      setTimeout(escribir, tiempoEscritura);
    }
  };
  escribir();
}
escritura("hola mundo    ", 500, 100, document.getElementById("texto"));
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="prin">
    <p id="texto" class="efecto">asdasdasd</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: la respuesta tuya me ayudó a que funcione pero ahora no les puedo aplicar un clearTimeOut, porque no se como se denomina la forma en que utilizas los setTimeOut. Ya que tengo un boton que cuando esta en una condicion aparece esta funcion pero cuando esta en la otra condicion desaparece el contenedor y cada vez que se vuelve a llamar se suman los tiempos de los intervalos y se interpone el texto

Comment: Pero eso ya es otra pregunta distinta... si quieres genera una nueva pregunta con el nuevo problema y te ayudaremos, saludos